# Admin login Google recaptcha: The response parameter is missing

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, recaptcha, mageplaza

After enabling Google Recaptcha for admin login, I am now locked from admin panel due to this error "The response parameter is missing."

How can I disable this?
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your admin username and password. Run the below command in your Magento root folder after editing the user and password

```
sudo php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="Admin@123" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Comment: It is google recaptcha by mageplaza that is not letting me sign in

Answer (score 0):

This is Magento core Google Recaptcha.

go to the database and hit the below query then flush the cache and check backend captcha is disabled.

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/backend/enabled';
```

you need to disabled third-party extension configuration then check in the **system.xml** file what is the exact path then based on configuration path update value in database **1** to **0**

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work. What could i try ?